# Oracle SQL full outer join

Tags: sql, oracle

I was joining 2 tables using FULL OUTER JOIN which took 6 minutes to run and give the output.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tab1 FULL OUTER JOIN tab2
ON tab1.id = tab2.id
;
```

I did the same thing using UNION of LEFT OUTER JOIN and RIGHT OUTER JOIN. This took only 15 seconds

```
SELECT *
FROM tab1, tab2
WHERE tab1.id (+) = tab2.id

UNION 

SELECT *
FROM tab1, tab2
WHERE tab1.id  = tab2.id (+)
;
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Have you checked the query plan for both queries?

Comment: Oracle recommends that the legacy (+) syntax should be avoided. Use the ISO standard LEFT / RIGHT JOIN syntax which is more universally understood and therefore more appropriate for a forum like SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have a lot of rows in both tables, few rows in common, and no index on the columns in question.

Answer (score 2):

Check the explain plans. Bear in mind that the two queries you specified are NOT logically equivalent. The second query eliminates duplicate rows (UNION) but the first one does not. This may be part of the explanation for the difference in performance.

Comment: Actually, both result sets should be the same.  The full outer join will not return duplicates because each set of join rows will only be found once.  If OP had used union all, then each set of joined rows would be returned twice.

Comment: @Allan: "both result sets should be the same". Only if both tables don't have any duplicate rows AND id is unique in at least one of the tables.

Comment: Okay, I can see the case where that would be true.  I guess, if the keys aren't unique, you'd have to use `union all` with three queries to accurately recreate the outer join (an inner join and two outer joins where matching sets are removed).

Answer (score 0):

`FULL OUTER JOIN` is somewhat different from the other join types since no single leading table can be selected.

The only method that would handle it efficiently would be a `MERGE JOIN`, however, `Oracle` won't select it.

Which plan does `Oracle` yield for your queries?

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this with Oracle 9.2. Could work around it by breaking the `FULL OUTER JOIN` down into a left outer join and a right anti-join (or something?).

```
SELECT a.*, b.*
from tableA a
left outer join tableB b on (a.a = b.a)
union all
SELECT a.*, b.*
from tableA a
right outer join tableB b on (a.a = b.a)
where a.a is null
```

This is pretty much the query you provided but using a `UNION ALL` and removing the duplicates from the second part of the query rather than using a `UNION`. Sometimes I couldn't even get performance out of that and needed to break the query down even further but can't remember what that involved.

For me the situation seemed to be improved with Oracle 10 but a `FULL OUTER JOIN` isn't something I need very often so haven't gone back to benchmark it recently.