# How to use inner join in oracle 11g?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, inner-join

I am running my Oracle query here but it's not working but the same query is working in SQL Server

Here is my query:

```
SELECT d.dept_code,
       d.dept_name,
       d.dept_desc,
       e.comp_name
FROM   dept_master d
       inner join comp_master e
               ON d.comp_id = e.comp_id
```

where in `dept_master.comp_id` value is the same as in `Dept_Master` table.

Comment: What is the Error you are getting?

Comment: Not getting any value only column name is showing.

Comment: can you please update your code like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6559261/left-outer-join-using-sign-in-oracle-11g

Comment: if you're not getting any results then that means either you join condition is wrong or there are no records matching the join condition

Comment: can give the table structures? like using 'desc dept_master' command

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are not getting any result is mainly because of the data

do this check to see if data is available in the tables

```
select * from dept_master;
select * from comp_master;
```

and see if both tables have any matching rows, i.e.; at least 1 row has same comp_id in both tables

I hope you will find the answer after doing this exercise

Comment: sir data is there in both tables but when i am fetching comp_id then it's containing some space and through that i am not able to join the query.

Comment: @Vikash do you whitespaces in comp_id?

Answer (score 1):

Is comp_id a character field? In that case define it as VARCHAR2 in Oracle. or try trim(d.comp_id) = trim(e.comp_id)

See a [demonstration in SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/15c89/2).