# Oracle SQL: joining with an empty table

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have say 3 tables, which have a key that links through all three like so...

```
select a.call_id, b.name, c.year
from table1 a, table2 b, table3 c
where a.call_id = b.call_id
and b.call_id = c.call_id
and a.call_id = 123
```

The problem is table 3 doesn't have a record that matches the id of 123, thus the entire query returns 0 rows, even though there is a match in tables 1 & 2.  Is there a way I can have oracle just return say null for the c.year field and still get results for a.call_id and b.name?

Comment: Without running multiple queries I may add (by multiple queries I mean running two separate select queries completely independent of each other

Comment: You want a LEFT OUTER JOIN.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6559261/left-outer-join-using-sign-in-oracle-11g

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have to use `LEFT` join:

```
select a.call_id, b.name, c.year
  from table1 a
    JOIN table2 b ON (a.call_id = b.call_id)
    LEFT JOIN table3 c ON (b.call_id = c.call_id)
  WHERE a.call_id = 123;
```

Read more about joins here: [Visual Explanation of Joins by Jeff Atwood](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Answer (score 2):

I guess you just need to translate this to JOIN:

```
SELECT a.call_id, b.name, c.year
from table1 a
JOIN table2 b
ON a.call_id = b.call_id
LEFT JOIN table3 c
ON and b.call_id = c.call_id
WHERE a.call_id = 123
```

Answer (score 1):

While you should use ANSI SQL, you could also do it the Oracle way with (+)

```
select a.call_id, b.name, c.year
from table1 a, table2 b, table3 c
where a.call_id = b.call_id
and b.call_id = c.call_id(+)
and a.call_id = 123
```