# MySQL (+), the meaning?

Tags: mysql, sql, null, sign

```
SELECT d.deptname, d.deptlocation, e.empname
FROM payroll.employee e, payroll.department d
WHERE e.deptno(+) = d.deptno
ORDER BY d.deptname, e.empname;
```

What does the (+) mean? Is that mean from employee table deptno Can be null?

Comment: Are you sure that is not Oracle your using?

Comment: Does that query even run in MySQL?

Comment: you can get more details at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6559261/left-outer-join-using-sign-in-oracle-11g

Comment: No valid MySQL syntax http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/32c9f/1

Answer (score 3):

this is an old **ORACLE**-syntax to create `OUTER JOIN`s. in your case, it means the same as

```
[...]
FROM
  payroll.department d
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  payroll.employee e
ON
  e.deptno = d.deptno
[...]
```

as others said in the comments, it's **not valid in MySQL**.

Answer (score 0):

`WHERE e.deptno(+) = d.deptno`  It means if `e.deptno` is not condition it will get to the query whatever.