# Is this an inner join in the on clause?

Tags: sql, t-sql, business-objects

Morning Folks,

This is my first encounter with joins being included in the WHERE clause and I'm probably going to ask a pretty basic question but is the following code snippet the equivalent to an INNER JOIN;

```
AND (Table1.Column1 = Table2.Column2(+))
```

I've been given a query taken from a business objects report and I'm trying to reproduce it in management studio with TSQL.

Comment: It's a [LEFT JOIN](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6559318/1679537).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is another common notation for joins. The + symbol is placed directly in the conditional statement and generally on the left side of the "=" (unlike the example given)

And it's easier if we remember this:
**+ is placed on the side of the optional table (the one which is allowed to contain empty or null values within the conditional).**

Answer (score 1):

It means

```
Table1 t1 Left Join Table2 t2 on t1.Column1 = t2.Column2
```